# How to call functions in a main view model from other view models?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, viewmodel

My program is composed of a `TreeView` and two `contentPresenters` at ground level. The mainWindow, `TreeView`, and each `contentPresenter` all have their own viewModels.

**I would like to call a function in the `mainWindowViewModel` from the `TreeViewViewModel`.**

I need to do this because the `mainWindowViewModel` controls what is displayed in the `contentPresenters`, and I would like to manually update the display.

I'm guessing I would do something like this...

**`TreeViewViewModel`:**

```
public class TreeViewViewModel
{
     //Do I need to declare the MainWindowVM?

     public TreeViewViewModel() { ... }

     private void function()
     {
          //Command that affects display

          //Manually call function in MainWindowVM to refresh View
     }
}
```

I have tried to get access to the `MainWindowVM` from the `TreeViewViewModel` by using:

```
public MainWindowViewModel ViewModel { get { return DataContext as MainWindowViewModel; } }
```

But it doesn't make much sense. because the MWVM is not the `DataContext` of the `TreeViewViewModel`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The `delegate` method used in this and the linked answer can be used in any parent-child relationship and in either direction. That includes from a child view model to a parent view model, a `Window` code behind to the code behind of a child `Window`, or even pure data relationships without any UI involved. You can find out more about using `delegate` objects from the [Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

I just answered a similar question to this earlier today. If you take a look at the [Passing parameters between viewmodels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19513555/passing-parameters-between-viewmodels/19514713#19514713) post, you'll see that the answer involves using `delegate` objects. You can simply replace these `delegate`s (from the answer) with your method(s) and it will work in the same way.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

---

UPDATE >>>

Yes, sorry I completely forgot you wanted to call methods instead... I've been working on too many posts tonight. So still using the example from the other post, just call your method in the `ParameterViewModel_OnParameterChange` handler:

```
public void ParameterViewModel_OnParameterChange(string parameter)
{
    // Call your method here
}
```

Think of the `delegate` as being your path back to the parent view model... it's like raising an event called `ReadyForYouToCallMethodNow.` In fact, you don't even need to have an input parameter. You could define your `delegate` like this:

```
public delegate void ReadyForUpdate();

public ReadyForUpdate OnReadyForUpdate { get; set; }
```

Then in the parent view model (after attaching the handler like in the other example):

```
public void ChildViewModel_OnReadyForUpdate()
{
    // Call your method here
    UpdateDisplay();
}
```

As you have multiple child view models, you could define the `delegate` in another class that they both have access to. Let me know if you have any more questions.

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

After reading your last comment again, I've just thought of a much simpler method that *might* achieve what you want... at least, if I understand you correctly. It is possible for you to `Bind` directly from your child views to your parent view model. For instance, this would allow you to `Bind` a `Button.Command` property in a child view to an `ICommand` property in your parent view model:

In `TreeViewView`:

```
<Button Content="Click Me" Command="{Binding DataContext.ParentCommand, 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type MainWindow}}}" />
```

This of course assumes that an instance of the parent view model in question is set as the `DataContext` of the `MainWindow`.

Comment: The only thing about this answer that's different than what I'm doing is that mainWindowViewModel is the parent ViewModel, which is what I'm trying to call to. How does that change this solution?

Comment: Using the example from the other post, you would have a `ParameterViewModel_OnParameterChange` handler method in your `MainWindowViewModel` class. The only difference is that your update in that handler is already where you want it to be (in the parent view model), so you wouldn't need to pass that `parameter` to the other child view model... effectively you can use the same example but just do what you want with the value in the `ParameterViewModel_OnParameterChange` handler instead of passing it to the other view model.

Comment: This seems to be about passing values to other ViewModels, and changing parameter values. I just want to call a function in `mainWindowViewModel` from a `Command`/Function in another ViewModel. The function in MWVM that I'm calling to just changes what's presented in the `contentPresenter` based on what's selected.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way is to pass a method as `Action` to the constructor of the child view model.

```
public class ParentViewModel
{
    ChildViewModel childViewModel;

    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        childViewModel = new ChildViewModel(ActionMethod);
    }

    private void ActionMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Parent method executed");
    }
}

public class ChildViewModel
{
    private readonly Action parentAction;

    public ChildViewModel(Action parentAction)
    {
         this.parentAction = parentAction;

         CallParentAction();
    }

    public void CallParentAction()
    {
        parentAction.Invoke();
    }
}
```