# ContentPresenter not updating display correctly

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, contentpresenter

In my program's main window I have a `TreeView` and a `ContentPresenter`. The display of the `ContentPresenter` is determined by what node is selected in the `TreeView`.

The name of one of my nodes is allowed to be changed by the user via `contentMenu`. All the user has to do is right click the node and select the new name out of the choices. The `ContentPresenter` is supposed to have a null display until the user chooses a name for the node.

The problem occurs when a new name is selected from the `contentMenu`. The `ContentPresenter`'s display changes, like it should, but only after the user selects a different node (changing the display), and then re-selects the original node.

How do I make it so that the display on the `ContentPresenter` changes right when the `TreeView` node's name is changed?

**TreeViewViewModel:**

```
public class TreeViewViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
     public TreeViewViewModel()
     {
          Node = new Node() { NodeName = "Blank", NodeDataModel = new NodeModel(),
                Commands = { new Command(nodeType_name1), new Command(nodeType_name2) } };
     }

     //These functions call to the NodeName property in the TreeView's Data Model
     private void nodeType_name1()
     {
          Node.NodeName = "Name1";
     }

     private void nodeType_name2()
     {
          Node.NodeName = "Name2";
     }
}
```

**XAML for MainWindow:**

```
<!-- Tree view items & Functions -->
<TreeView Name="Tree_One" ItemsSource="{Binding DataTree.Data}" ... >
     <TreeView.Resources>
           <SolidColorBrush Color="LightSkyBlue" x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" />
     </TreeView.Resources>
 </TreeView>

 <!--- Left Widget -->
 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding LeftWidget}" />
```

**MainWindowViewModel:**

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : PropertyChangedBase
{
     private TreeViewViewModel _dataTree;

     public MainWindowViewModel()
     {
          _dataTree = new TreeViewViewModel();
     }

     public TreeViewViewModel DataTree { ... }

     //This function is in charge of changing the display of the ContentPresenter
     // I think that my problem can probably be solved by doing something here
     public void ChangeViews()
     {
          if (_dataTree.SelectedItem is Node)
          {
               var _node = _dataTree.SelectedItem as Node;
               var nodeViewModel = new NodeViewModel(_node.NodeDataModel);

               if (_node.NodeName== "Unknown")
                    LeftWidget = null; //This is the Content Presenter **
               if (_node.NodeName == "Name1")
               {
                   LeftWidget = nodeViewModel;
               }

               if (_node.NodeName == "Name2") {...}
          }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Duh, thats a alot of code and its pretty difficult to understand what you up to since you seem to have controls in your ViewModel.

Or at least it looks to me that you have them in ViewModel. That is not very MVVM-alike my friend. :)

*"The problem occurs when a new name is selected from the contentMenu. The ContentPresenter's display changes, like it should, but only after the user selects a different node (changing the display), and then re-selects the original node."*

The property changed is not being fired because the new selected value is equal to the old one.

Pretty obvious, right?... no property was actually changed

But why do you want the ContentPresenter to update itself with the value that it already has?

You said when you select a node the ContentPresenter displays it properly and when you re-select the same the ContentPresenter is not doing anything.

Its not doing anything because it think it doesnt need to. Which is true.

So the question is why would you make ContentPresenter force to refresh on each value no matter if old value is the same as new one?

Though if you want to hack/trick a little bit, you can always set ContentPresenter's Content to null before you assign another value. :)

However, post us more code and we will be able to provide you a better solution to your issue.

Comment: I would just like to make a few clarifications: First, I do not have controls in my ViewModel, `LeftWidget` is a property bound to the `Content` of the `ContentPresenter`. Second, I'd like to go over the problem again, since it doesn't look like I explained it well enough -- When the node is selected and the name is "unknown", the `ContentPreseter` is BLANK. The user changes the name, with the node still selected, but the panel remains BLANK (should display a new panel). The new panel is only displayed once the user desects the node, selectes a new one, and the re-selects the primary node.

Comment: So basically you have to click on something else, and then go back before the `Content` changes in the `ContentPresenter`.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this issue by calling `ChangeViews();` in my MainWindowViewModel from my TreeViewViewModel. I did this by using a delegate property in the TVVM, and adding it to my MWVM. By doing this, the display is updated whenever `ChangeViews();` is called.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522202/if-necessary-how-to-call-functions-in-mainviewviewmodel-from-other-viewmodels) is the answer that I used.