# Use value from wpf main window in user space

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, space

My problem is this:
I'm trying to code an c# wpf application in in which the user can select an item from a combobox in the main window. I then want to pass that value on to a user control, which is then supposed to print data referring to the selected comboBoxItem onto the screen. 
How can I achieve this? 
Regards
Curtis

Comment: show us your effort, your code, what have you tried?

Comment: you can simply create property in UserControl and before opening in control just assign value to that particular property and at usercontrol level you will have that property in hand

Comment: OK, just before checking stackexchange again, I found a workaround. Although I don't think it's very elegant.
I created an instance of my user control in my main window code and then passed 'object sender' to a function called 'updateList(object sender)' in my user control. 
In my updateList method in the user control I can then use the selected item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways for you to pass a value from the `MainWindow` to a child `Window` or `UserControl`. One of the simplest ways is for you to declare a [`DependencyProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914(v=vs.110).aspx) in your `UserControl` and then data bind to that property in the `MainWindow` in XAML:

```
<ComboBox Name="Combo" ... />
<YourPrefix:YourUserControl YourProperty="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=Combo}" />
```

This will update the property value in your `UserControl` each time the user selects another item.

Please see my answer to the [How to call functions in a main view model from other view models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522202/how-to-call-functions-in-a-main-view-model-from-other-view-models/19522419#19522419) question for a more complex and flexible way to pass values.

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that. I haven't done anything with data binding yet and since I've stumbled across it so many times, it's definitely worth having a look at.