# nested User Control binding not working for nested property

Tags: c#, data-binding

i have three usercontrol in a C# win application ; the main User is called UcReferenteTecnico that only contains UcContatto that has a nested usercontrol UcIndirizzo.
UcContatto has a modelView named ContattoMV and UcIndirizzo has a modelview named IndirizzoMV

UcContatto modelview has a properies and a nested IndirizzoMV properties; they are done in this way:

```
public class ContattoMV:INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    string _NOME_CONTATTO;
    [HeaderAttribute("Nome contatto", true, 2)]
    public string NOME_CONTATTO
    {
        get { return _NOME_CONTATTO; }
        set
        {
            _NOME_CONTATTO = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("NOME_CONTATTO");
        }
    }
    public IndirizzoMV Indirizzo
    {
        get { return _Indirizzo; }
        set
        {
            _Indirizzo = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Indirizzo");
        }
    }
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string aiPropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(aiPropertyName));
        }
    }
}
public class IndirizzoMV:INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string TOPONIMO
    {
        get { return _TOPONIMO; }
        set
        {
            _TOPONIMO = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("TOPONIMO");
        }
    }
    public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string aiPropertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(aiPropertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

All properties are binding in UcContatto and in UcIndirizzo to Control in this way:
In UcContatto:

```
this.txtNome.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("EditValue", this._bsContatto, "NOME_CONTATTO", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

and to bind nested usercontrol UcIndirizzo do this:

```
this.ucIndirizzo1.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("BsIndirizzo", this._bsContatto, "Indirizzo", true));
```

where _bsContatto is typeof ContattoMV and BsIndirizzo is bindable properties done in this way:

```
[Bindable(true)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public IndirizzoMV BsIndirizzo
{
    get
    {
        return (IndirizzoMV)_bsIndirizzo.DataSource;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        _bsIndirizzo.DataSource = value;
    }
}
```

In UcIndirizzo properites is binding in this way:

```
this.txtToponimo.DataBindings.Add(new System.Windows.Forms.Binding("EditValue", this._bsIndirizzo, "TOPONIMO", true, System.Windows.Forms.DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged));
```

where _bsIndirizzo is typeof IndirizzoMV.
In UcContatto to spread properties to main UserControl i use another bindable properties in this way:

```
[Bindable(true)]
[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
public ContattoMV BsContatto
{
    get
    {
        return (ContattoMV)_bsContatto.DataSource;
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        _bsContatto.DataSource = value;
    }
}
```

to initialize usercontrol in main Control UcReferenteTecnico i do this:

```
this.ucContatto1.BsContatto = new ContattoMV();
```

when i change value in my usercontrol if i set value in txtNome , NOME_CONTATTO properties is valued (enter in breakpoint put in set properties)
if i change value in ucIndirizzo in txtToponimo no properties is valued

where is my error?
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that your error is *not using XAML to define your `Binding`s*, but I guess that you might have some valid reason for that. I found it really difficult to follow your question because of all of the foreign type and property names, so while I don't think that I can help directly with your problem, I can provide this simple advice:

When you want to data bind to a property that is in a parent view model, you can simply use a `RelativeSource Binding`:

Imagine that this was in the parent view model:

```
public string NOME_CONTATTO
{
    get { return _NOME_CONTATTO; }
    set
    {
        _NOME_CONTATTO = value;
        NotifyPropertyChanged("NOME_CONTATTO");
    }
}
```

You could data bind to it directly from any child view like this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding DataContext.NOME_CONTATTO, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Local:ParentView}}}" ... />
```

Alternatively, if you just want to pass some value between view models, you can use `delegate`s... see my answer to the [How to call functions in a main view model from other view models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522202/how-to-call-functions-in-a-main-view-model-from-other-view-models/19522419#19522419) question to find out how to do that.