# DataBinding ListView ItemTemplate UserControl

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

I have a ListView on my Windows Universal page.  I am using a UserControl to define my ItemTemplate so that I can use the RelativePanel and VisualStateManager to control how my items appear depending on the screen size...

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllThings}"
          ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <local:CrossingControl />
         </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

I have a button in my UserControl where I want to bind its Command to a command property in the ViewModel that is the DataContext of the list itself...

```
<UserControl ...>
    <RelativePanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="crossedEntryPanel">
        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.DeleteCommand,
                          RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

I have tried using the ElementName binding, but it doesn't seem to work (I suppose because my listview element name is defined in another xaml file).  I have also tried the above RelativeSource binding, but that doesn't seem to work either.  How can I bind this properly?

Comment: What about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522202/how-to-call-functions-in-a-main-view-model-from-other-view-models

Comment: Doesn't quite solve my problem I'm afraid. The relativesource with ancestor type doesn't seem to be available in windows universal

Comment: How about having the `DeleteCommand` moved inside the `CrossingControl`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of `Tag` property to save the `DataContext` of `ListView` and use it in `UserControl`

Here how it is done

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AllThings}" x:Name="listview"
                        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListViewItemStyle}">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <local:CrossingControl  Tag="{Binding DataContext,ElementName=listview}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>

<UserControl x:Name="usercontrol" ...>
    <RelativePanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="crossedEntryPanel">
        <Button Command="{Binding Tag.DeleteCommand,ElementName=usercontrol}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"
```

**RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}":-** this points to `controltemplate` of `button`