# Access the button of one xaml page from another xaml page

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app

In my UWP application i have three xaml pages.In first xaml page i have a button click event. I want to access this button click event from the third page. Is it possible ?

Comment: Can you share what you've done so far?

Comment: There are solutions but more important: You should not need or want this,

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can pass parameters between pages like that:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(TargetPage), 19);
```

On the `TargetPage` override the `OnNavigatedTo` method like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {
        var myAge = e.Parameter + 3;
    }
}
```

In this case the value of `myAge`variable should be 19 + 3 = 22;
However, you have to check if `e.Parameter` is not `null` when your navigation model provides navigation from multiple pages (which do not pass any parameters) to the current one.

Also, best practices from [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame#methods):

> The parameter value can have a complex type if you do not use
>   GetNavigationState(). However, you should still use only basic types
>   in order to avoid excess memory usage caused by the frame’s navigation
>   stack holding a reference to the parameter. A preferred approach is to
>   not pass the actual object, but instead pass an identifier that you
>   can use to look up the object in the target landing page. For example,
>   instead of passing a `Customer` object, pass a reference to the
>   `CustomerID`, then look up the `Customer` after the navigation is
>   complete.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with MVVM pattern. You could call methods from other ViewModels.

For example like the following:

```
public class FirstViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand buttonClickCmd { get; set; }

    public FirstViewModel()
    {
        buttonClickCmd = new RelayCommand(Click);
    }

    public void Click()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Clicked");
    }
}

public class ThirdViewModel:ViewModelBase
{
    public RelayCommand ClickFromFirstCmd { get; set; }

    public ThirdViewModel()
    {
        ClickFromFirstCmd = new RelayCommand(Click);
    }

    public void Click()
    {
        FirstViewModel firstviewmodel = new FirstViewModel();
        firstviewmodel.Click();
    }
}
```

You could check [How to call functions in a main view model from other view models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19522202/how-to-call-functions-in-a-main-view-model-from-other-view-models) for more details.