# WPF share common property between controls

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

i've two content controls how can i share a common property between them,
for example if i select some value from combobox in the first content control,
how can the second control know it

```
<telerikNavigation:RadTabItem Header="1">
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding EGRPExtractViewModel.View}" />                    
    </StackPanel>
</telerikNavigation:RadTabItem>
        <telerikNavigation:RadTabItem Header="2">
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding EGRPRightObjectViewModel.View}" />
</telerikNavigation:RadTabItem>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to use two way binding then respond to the property changing in your ViewModel.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding EGRPRightObjectViewModel.View,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

See the MSDN docs for how to respond to changed properties: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: But EGRPRightObjectViewModel.View actually is UserControl

Comment: Ah yes, I read that too quickly. As the other answer states you'd need a control property which exposes the selected value to bind to.

Answer (score 0):

You do not bind view properties. You can bind *control* properties in same view, so one possibility for you will be to create a control which exposes bindable properties specifically for this reason.

When using mvvm normally view-model should provide **all needed properties** to the view. If it's a property from another view-model, then it is still have to be provided by **view-model of this view** (search for questions about how to pass data between view-models to example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19513555/1997232) is one).